# Create google map with javascript after Classic maps gone

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am not pro, so my question may sounds strange: I prefer to embed maps on my website using java, so I can add events on clicks etc:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function initialize() {
var mapOptions = {
center: new google.maps.LatLng(44.1471311,9.6500556),
zoom: "14",
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);
```

etc.

When I was using Classic maps I just used "Previews" option, so I move the map in the window and then export all info, where I can find coordinates of the center, zoom etc.

Now I don't have this option. I create my map in google, export KML so I have coordinates of all icons and then I start to guess the center's coordinates so my map fit in the way I like (I don't like auto option), I just change them, upload the change on server and see if look good or not, so I do this about 50 times until I find a perfect position. Is there another way? Maybe I am missing something?

Comment: When you say "java" do you mean javascript? (the code posted looks like the Google Maps Javascript API v3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create your own "linkto" map, which captures the center and zoom in the URL (or in a text field):

[example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_linktomap.html?lat=44.807174&lng=-86.114148&zoom=7&type=m)

[tutorial page from Mike Williams' v2 tutorial](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/linktothis.htm)

code snippet:

```js
// Before we go looking for the passed parameters, set some defaults
// in case there are no patameters
var lat = 0;
var lng = 0;
var zoom = 0;
var maptype = google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP;
var map = null;

function MapTypeId2UrlValue(maptype) {
  var urlValue = 'm';
  switch (maptype) {
    case google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID:
      urlValue = 'h';
      break;
    case google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE:
      urlValue = 'k';
      break;
    case google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN:
      urlValue = 't';
      break;
    default:
    case google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP:
      urlValue = 'm';
      break;
  }
  return urlValue;
}

// ========== This function will create the "link to this page"
function makeLink() {
  var a = location + "?lat=" + map.getCenter().lat().toFixed(6) + "&lng=" + map.getCenter().lng().toFixed(6) + "&zoom=" + map.getZoom() + "&type=" + MapTypeId2UrlValue(map.getMapTypeId());
  document.getElementById("link").innerHTML = '<a href="' + a + '">Link to this page<\/a>';
  document.getElementById('centerZoom').innerHTML = a;
}

function initialize() {

  // ========== Read paramaters that have been passed in ==========


  // If there are any parameters at eh end of the URL, they will be in  location.search
  // looking something like  "?lat=50&lng=-3&zoom=10&type=h"

  // skip the first character, we are not interested in the "?"
  var query = location.search.substring(1);

  // split the rest at each "&" character to give a list of  "argname=value"  pairs
  var pairs = query.split("&");
  for (var i = 0; i < pairs.length; i++) {
    // break each pair at the first "=" to obtain the argname and value
    var pos = pairs[i].indexOf("=");
    var argname = pairs[i].substring(0, pos).toLowerCase();
    var value = pairs[i].substring(pos + 1).toLowerCase();
    // alert("argname="+argname+" ,value="+value);
    // process each possible argname
    if (argname == "lat") {
      lat = parseFloat(value);
    }
    if (argname == "lng") {
      lng = parseFloat(value);
    }
    if (argname == "zoom") {
      zoom = parseInt(value);
    }
    if (argname == "type") {
      // from the v3 documentation 8/24/2010
      // HYBRID This map type displays a transparent layer of major streets on satellite images. 
      // ROADMAP This map type displays a normal street map. 
      // SATELLITE This map type displays satellite images. 
      // TERRAIN This map type displays maps with physical features such as terrain and vegetation. 
      if (value == "m") {
        maptype = google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP;
      }
      if (value == "k") {
        maptype = google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE;
      }
      if (value == "h") {
        maptype = google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID;
      }
      if (value == "t") {
        maptype = google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN;
      }

    }
  }

  // ========== Create the map using the information obtained above ========
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: zoom,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
    mapTypeId: maptype
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);

  // Make the link the first time when the page opens
  makeLink();

  // Make the link again whenever the map changes
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'maptypeid_changed', makeLink);
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'center_changed', makeLink);
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', makeLink);
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', makeLink);
}


// This Javascript is based on code provided by the
// Community Church Javascript Team
// http://www.bisphamchurch.org.uk/   
// http://econym.org.uk/gmap/
// from the v2 tutorial page at:
// http://econym.org.uk/gmap/example_linktothis.htm
//]]>

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```html
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="centerZoom"></div>
<div id="map" style="width: 550px; height: 450px"></div>
<div id="link"></div>
```

Comment: Awesome! I've just created the button, so I can print info that I need (taken from your code):
console.log('zoom:' + map.getZoom());
console.log('lat=' + map.getCenter().lat().toFixed(6) + ' lng=' + map.getCenter().lng().toFixed(6));